# Prove $\binom{n}{1} - \frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{2} + \frac{1}{3}\binom{n}{3} + \ldots = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

I thought of induction but that was unwieldy. Then considered using $(1+x)^n$. Didn't succeed.

Any hint?
Thanks

Comment: *Hint.* The sum can be understood as the value of $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-(1-x)^n}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}\,dx$$ where $y=1-x$.

Comment: I tried this: 

$\int \frac{(1-x)^n}{x}dx = \ln x - x\binom {n}{1} + \frac{x^2}{2}\binom{n}{2} - \ldots $ but didnt know how to proceed with the LHS. Now with your hint, I can replace LHS (taking $\ln x$ the other side) with $1 + y+y^2+...$ and integrating this we will get the harmonic series... Cool. Thanks

Comment: No worries. And I found that the question has already been answered in this community, so let me provide the link as well.